# Can we restore database to SQL Server 2017 taken from SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

Can we restore a database which is created and have some data in SQL Server 2012. But, now i want to migrate from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2017. Is it possible to take backup in SQL Server 2012 and restore it to SQL Server 2017. I need some other solutions if not possible to restore it. Because, it's almost 30GB of data, i can't get it back if not possible to restore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, SQL Server is backward compatible. You can restore a database from any previous version of SQL Server that was *supported at the time of the release*. For SQL Server 2017, you can therefore restore databases from SQL Server 2008 to 2017.

SQL Server, however, is **not** forward compatible. Once a database is restored on a more recent version of SQL Server you cannot create a back up of that database and restore it to an older version; even if the database had the correct compatibility setting. The upgrade process is **one way**.

Answer (score 0):

"Once a database is restored on a more recent version of SQL Server you cannot create a back up of that database and restore it to an older version", But as a work around you can script database and execute it in an older version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).